# Copy Objects from Get-Random

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I want to pull random images from a directory, so I use `Get-ChildItem` with the desired parameters to identify all relevant images, then have them write to a `CSV` file. From there, I import the `CSV` and use `Get-Random` to pull the random files. I then want to copy the images from `Get-Random` but I cant get it to work.

I know the `CSV` is correct, and when I call the `Get-Random` variable, it looks correct (I believe it's a hashtable?).

CSV Contents:

```
Image                                                                                                              
-----                                                                                                              
\\Path\File1.jpg
\\Path\File2.jpg
\\Path\File3.jpg
```

Script to pull random image and copy over:

```
$a = Import-CSV -Path $path
    $selects = Get-Random -InputObject $a -Count $count
        foreach($b in $selects){
        Copy-Item $destination
        }
```

When I echo the `$selects`, it does accuratley name random files from the original `GCI`, but I can't figure out the copy part. Maybe it's because its a hashtable? I believe `Get-Random` provides `objects` and I think objects can use `Copy-Item`. I'm over my head.

Thanks

Comment: have you stepped thru your code in debugger like VSCode or ISE?  put a breakpoint on your Copy-Item and check syntax on that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumnavigate the issue by completely removing the `CSV` element. Initially a `Get-Childitem` and `Add-Content` built out the `CSV`, instead of doing that I have piped the `GCI` directly into the `Get-Random` and then used `Copy-Item` successfully:

`$a = GCI $directory | Get-Random -Count $Count
$a | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination`

Thanks for everyone's input, it helped me think outside my current constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing or piping the object to `Copy-Item`, you could simply do `$selects | Copy-Item -Destination $destination`

Comment: `$selects.Image` I would guess since the csv object will have members.  I am not at a place to test any code.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right on that (I have not tested it either, I just wanted to point out the main point that was missing)

Comment: While the paths listed in the csv look correct, when I use the above command, the Copy-Item fails claiming: `Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'H:\@{Image=\Path\Image.jpg}' because it does not exist.` It's adding a local drive (H:) and brackets. The path should be `\\Path\Image.jpg`